# Отправить и вернуть модель из представления

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp

Имеется 2 метода одного контроллера. Первый отправляет в представление обьект модели. На представлении расположена форма, в которой отображаются некоторые свойства обьекта, но пользователь вводит новые данные и тем самым дополняет обьект и отправляет его во второй метод. Выглядить это примерно так :

1 метод

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string Id)
{
   return View(new DownloadModel() { Idfile = Id, IsIdCorrect = true });
}
```

представление

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("file", "download"))
{
        <p>Id файла : <input type="text" name = "Idfile" value="@Model.Idfile"></p>
        <p>Введите пароль от файла</p>
        <p><input type="password" name="Password"/> </p>
        <p><input  type="submit"/></p>
}
```

2 метод

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult file(DownloadModel model)
{ ...
```

Вопрос - какой html контролл можно использовать что бы отобразить свойство `Model.Idfile` вместо инпута так, что бы оно вместе с паролем попало во второй метод ? Сейчас я использую инпут но это не удобно и не безопасно - пользователь может начать вводить свои собственные значения, чем его заменить ?

upd

попробовал просто скрывать инпут но на некоторых браузерах он все еще виден.

```
    <input type="hidden" name="Idfile" value="@Model.Idfile">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну скройте его, `<input type="hidden" ...>` а юзеру показывайте label или просто текстом.

Comment: @tym32167 а ведь точно. совсем об этом не подумал. спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, что Вы отправляете на клиент и получаете с клиента обратно, может быть изменено на клиентской стороне, и верить этому нельзя. Так что пассаж "на некоторых браузерах" должен читаться как "на всех браузерах". Если Вы не хотите, чтобы `Idfile` был виден пользователю, его надо хранить на сервере, например, в сессии.